# this function should return something but it ain't,

Tags: python

```
def harry():
    x = 88
    def rohan():
        global x
        x = 5
        print("Before",x)
        rohan()
        print("After",x)
```

harry()
print(x)

Oputput should be
Before 88
After 88
5

Comment: Your indentation is messed up in the post, but it looks like you never call `rohan()` except from inside `rohan()`.

Comment: what should i do

Comment: You say *"this function should return something but it ain't"* - well, **you** never `return` anything, what did you expect?

Comment: then how to get printed the things in rohan()

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `rohan()` in `harry()` first off. Secondly, you're going to get a `RecursionError` once you've fixed that. You need a way to stop recursing if you've met some condition.

If you're trying to show that x was 5 and then got changed to 88, then you'd want to write your function like this:

```
def harry():
    x = 88
    print("Before",x)
    x = 5
    print("After",x)

harry()
```

Result:

```
Before 88
After 5
```

And if you're trying to return something in python and give it any number you want you'll need a `return` statement:

```
def before(x):
    print('Before',x)
    return(x)

def after(x):
    x = 5
    print('After', x)

initial_number = before(5)
after(initial_number)
```

Result:

```
Before 5
After 5
```

If you're deadset on getting the results out of `rohan()` you can do this:

```
def harry():
    x = 88
    def rohan(x):
        if x != 5:
            print("Before",x)
            print("After",x)
        if x == 5:
            print(x)
            return
        x = 5
        rohan(x)
    rohan(x)

harry()
```

Which will result in:

```
Before 88
After 88
5
```

I highly recommend you read the [functions part of the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)